# WPF design time ICollectionView binding silently fails

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, icollectionview

I have both `ICollectionView` and `ObservableCollection<ItemVM>` (for now) exposed from view model:

```
public ICollectionView ItemsView
{
    get => !IsInDesignMode ? _itemsView :
            CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(new ObservableCollection<Item>());
    set => Set(ref _itemsView, value));
}

public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
{
    get => _items;
    private set => Set(ref _items, value);
}
```

and both of them are bound to `ItemsSource` of a `DataGrid`:

```
<StackPanel d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type={x:Type vm:ItemsTestVM}}">
    <DataGrid Name="DG1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
    <DataGrid Name="DG2" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsView}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

while **both** display items in runtime, only the **DG1** (observable-bound one) display (three dummy) rows in design-time. 
Why is that and how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

From what you have shown, **it silently works**...for the design time logic does not return a viable data set to show; just an *empty observable collection*.

In design mode only, an empty view is returned because there is no association between any (design time) existing data that you must be doing as in the `Items` property (which works).

Look at the creation of the view...where is the observable collection getting data?

```
  CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(new ObservableCollection<Item>())
```